# Python JQUERY like syntax to mimic Unix Shell Pipelines

Tags: python, unix

I am not sure if this has been asked before, but I was wondering how can we implement a "set oriented" like syntax in python to mimic the UNIX SHELL pipelines.
In particular, how to use "plain python functions" that can produce, modify, or consume a stream of records, and can be glued together using the "." operator.

A straightforward example assuming python functions like Unix programs:

In unix we can do:

```
    ls | egrep '^a' | wc -l
```

to count the files in the current directory that start with 'a'.
How about:

```
    from  unixtools import *
    ls().egrep('^a').wc(countLines=True)
```

and the implementation of ls could be like a generator:

```
    @pipeline
    def ls():
       for file in glob.glob("*"):
          yield file
```

I have omitted the obvious glue code, which will make it possible to connect the **ls** with the other "commands" of the pipeline.

**@pipeline** is an attempt to use decorators to convert the plain python function into a member of the pipeline protocol.

I realise this can be done using the traditional syntax of python, which is less readable forcing you to write in reverse, and more error prone:

```
     wc(countLines=True,input=egrep("^a",input=ls()))
```

I guess we could study the implementation of python **pyquery** to figure it out.

Comment: The term you're looking for is [**fluent interface**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Method chaining is possible, decorators are possible, DSL with overridden | operator [is possible](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe), what is the question?

Comment: Thanks for the info.
more googling revealed: "Pipe: infix syntax for Python" :
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipe/1.3
(https://mdk.fr/blog/pipe-infix-syntax-for-python.html)  which is closer

Comment: Another related article is "Collection Pipelines" (https://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/)

and a reference to the book: Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture Volume 1: A System of Patterns Volume 1 Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the python pipe package is VERY close to what I was asking, and I was not aware of it.

So, I am answering my own question since the pipe package documentation was not very intuitive for my stated problem. Especially when it comes to implementing the full unix shell pipe semantics. At the end, there exist some more unresolved questions regarding some common unix tricks.

We can create a producer as a python generator, using the @Pipe decorator.
Be warned, this type of producer can only be the first member of the pipeline:

```
from pipe import Pipe
@Pipe
def producer(arg=10):
    for x in range(arg):
         yield x
```

Like in Unix, you can define a transformer, which is expected to transform its input and generate output:

```
@Pipe
def transformer(iterable, arg=2):
    for x in iterable:
         if x % arg == 0: yield x*2
```

We can hook up producer and transformer using the "pipe" syntax, which resembles that of the Unix Shell pipeline:

```
producer() | transformer()
```

Unlike Unix shell, this produces nothing as output ;-(
You may write a consumer, which consumes its input and prints something:

```
@Pipe
def consumer(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        print(x)
```

and now the hookup will work as expected:

```
producer() | transformer() | consumer()
```

Interestingly, on the second or more pipeline element, we can omit the parenthesis and just use the name of the Pipe function:

```
producer(10) | transformer | consumer
```

Another feature I liked, is the equivalent of SHELL "here document":

```
[1,2,3,4] | transformer | consumer
```

In this case [1,2,3,4] is interpreted as a sequence of values a generator could have been produced and it is "piped" to the next element in the pipeline.

And we can of course collect the pipeline results:

```
a = [1,2,3,4] |  transformer | consumer
```

---

And now finally some cases it is not very obvious how to deal with "pipe":

It is not clear how to do the equivalent of stdout merging in the SHELL:

```
(echo today ; date) | wc
```

Maybe using a "cat" producer, able to concatenate all of its iterable inputs?

```
cat(echo("today"),date()) | ...
```

It is not also clear how to consume just a few elements of the pipeline and then continue with another function, like in the UNIX SHELL:

```
cat /etc/passwd | (read line ; cat)
```

In this case, read consumes the first line and cat sees the rest of them. Can we overload the "(" and ")" symbols?